# Webix DataTable - expand object properties

Tags: javascript, datatable, webix

If I have a list of (JavaScript) objects in the following form:

```
var results = [
  {'name': 'mary', 'availability' : { 'monday': 'True', 'tuesday': 'False' ... } },
  {'name': 'john', 'availability' : { 'monday': 'False', 'tuesday': 'False' ... } },
  {'name': 'pete', 'availability' : { 'monday': 'True', 'tuesday': 'True' ... } }
]
```

how do I display this data in a Webix `DataTable`, having each of the days in `availability` as a column?

My configuration object for the `DataTable` looks like this:

```
var dtable = webix.ui({
    ....
    view:"datatable",
    id: "nameTable",
    columns:[
        { id: "name",                 header:"Name"},
        { id: "availability.monday",  header:'Mon'},
        { id: "availability.tuesday", header:'Tue'}, 
        ...
    ],
    data:results,
    ...        
});
```

I have also tried: `id: "availability['mon']"` which doesn't work or report any error.  If I just do : `id:"availability"`, in the browser I see that it shows `[object Object]` for each row.

I've also tried the [autoconfig option](http://docs.webix.com/datatable__columns_configuration.html#automaticcolumnconfiguration) but that doesn't render anything (no errors).

I have tried to find examples in [the documentation](http://docs.webix.com/datatable__columns_configuration.html#externaldatasourceforthecolumn) but haven't found any so far.  I'm sure this must be possible without having to restructure my incoming data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native support for complex properties in the Webix DataTable. You can use "template" property of column object to show any property of data object as value of a column, though.

```
columns:[
    { id: "col1", template:"#availability.monday#"},
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling this might have been the case.  Looks like I need to spend some more time going over the documentation and tutorials to use the framework more effectively.